# Unexpected behaviour with Coefficient

Tags: functions, bugs, pattern-matching, coefficients

**Bug introduced in version 12.2 or earlier. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

If I run

```
expr = (CF G[0, zb])/(1 - zb) + (CF zb^2 G[0, zb])/(1 - zb) + (2 CF G[1, zb])/(1 - zb) + (2 CF zb^2 G[1, zb])/(1 - zb);
Coefficient[expr, zb, -1]
```

in Mathematica 12.1, it returns

```
-((CF G[0, zb])/(-1 + zb)) - (2 CF G[1, zb])/(-1 + zb)
```

Shouldn't it return 0 since there are no terms in the form *1/zb* in *expr* ?

Comment: Definitely a bug. Also remaining in 12.2. It appears to be fixed in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = (CF G[0, zb])/(1 - zb) + (CF zb^2 G[0, zb])/(1 - 
      zb) + (2 CF G[1, zb])/(1 - zb) + (2 CF zb^2 G[1, zb])/(1 - zb);
Coefficient[expr, zb, -1]
```

> [image: 0]

Screenshot

> [image: screen]